# M-x slime [No match]

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, sbcl, slime

I installed `Emacs 29.2` and `sbcl 2.4.0`.

Then I installed `slime` using the command `M-x package-install<Ret>slime<Ret>`.  I can see that slime is installed (M-x list-packages):

[image]

Now, I'm trying to get slime to work following [these instructions](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/41237/15353):

> It is simple as:
>
> 1. Open emacs
> 2. Open your lisp file with fibonacci function
> 3. Issue M-x slime
> 4. Place you cursor over fibonacci function and press C-c C-c to evaluate/compile it in Slime.
> 5. switch to slime window and call (fibonacci 10)
>
> Screenshot example with hello-world function:

In emacs, I opened a hello world `.lisp` file with `C-x C-f`. However, when I type `M-x slime<Ret>`, I get `[No match]`.  Same for `M-x slime-mode<Ret>`.

Here is my `~/.emacs` file:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-selected-packages '(slime paredit)))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;; I added the following according to slime install directions:

(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
```

`sbcl` is in my path:

```
% which sbcl
/opt/local/bin/sbcl

% echo $PATH
...:/Users/7stud/bin/:/opt/local/bin:....
```

I tried altering the .emacs file to use the full path to `sbcl`:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/opt/local/bin/sbcl")
```

but I still get `M-x slime [No match]`.  I've been quitting emacs and relaunching it after I make changes to the `.emacs` file.

Here is my `~/.emacs.d/elpa` directory (which I haven't touched):

```
% ls
archives               macrostep-0.9.2.signed slime-2.29.1
gnupg                  paredit-26             slime-2.29.1.signed
macrostep-0.9.2        paredit-26.signed
```

There were a bunch of warnings when I installed slime, but I can't find where those warnings are logged, so I can't post them.

I was able to successfully install and use the package `paredit`. When I open a .lisp file, it opens in Lisp major-mode, and if I do `M-x paredit-mode`, that adds Paredit as a minor-mode:

[image]

After adding Paredit as a minor-mode, parentheses get matched, so it works.

I'm on `macOS 12.5.1`, and I installed emacs with:

```
% sudo port install emacs-app
```

**Edit: =======**

I unistalled slime by displaying the package list, `M-x list-packages`, then searching for the slime listing, `C-s`, then typing `d` on the slime listing, then typing `x`.  I reinstalled slime by finding the slime listing again, then typing `i` on the slime line, then `x`.  Here are the warnings:

```
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-autodoc.el:51:17: Warning: ‘eldoc-message’ is an obsolete function (as of eldoc-1.1.0); use ‘eldoc-documentation-functions’ instead.
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-autodoc.el:52:15: Warning: ‘eldoc-message’ is an obsolete function (as of eldoc-1.1.0); use ‘eldoc-documentation-functions’ instead.
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-autodoc.el:64:8: Warning: ‘eldoc-message’ is an obsolete function (as of eldoc-1.1.0); use ‘eldoc-documentation-functions’ instead.
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-autodoc.el:106:8: Warning: ‘font-lock-fontify-buffer’ is for interactive use only; use ‘font-lock-ensure’ or ‘font-lock-flush’ instead.
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-autodoc.el:165:14: Warning: ‘eldoc-display-message-p’ is an obsolete function (as of eldoc-1.6.0); Use ‘eldoc-documentation-functions’ instead.
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-autodoc.el:166:10: Warning: ‘eldoc-message’ is an obsolete function (as of eldoc-1.1.0); use ‘eldoc-documentation-functions’ instead.
⛔ Warning (comp): bridge.el:115:2: Warning: defvar `bridge-leftovers' docstring wider than 80 characters
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-cl-indent.el:115:2: Warning: custom-declare-variable `lisp-align-keywords-in-calls' docstring has wrong usage of unescaped single quotes (use \= or different quoting)
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-cl-indent.el:1448:2: Warning: defvar `common-lisp-indent-clause-joining-loop-macro-keyword' docstring has wrong usage of unescaped single quotes (use \= or different quoting)
⛔ Warning (comp): hyperspec.el:1320:4: Warning: Alias for ‘common-lisp-hyperspec-glossary-function’ should be declared before its referent
⛔ Warning (comp): slime.el:112:2: Warning: Alias for ‘slime-contribs’ should be declared before its referent
⛔ Warning (comp): slime.el:277:12: Warning: defcustom for ‘slime-completion-at-point-functions’ fails to specify type
⛔ Warning (comp): slime.el:689:4: Warning: Doc string after `declare'
⛔ Warning (comp): slime.el:1160:6: Warning: ‘byte-compile-file’ called with 2 arguments, but accepts only 1
⛔ Warning (comp): slime.el:2408:10: Warning: ‘hide-entry’ is an obsolete function (as of 25.1); use ‘outline-hide-entry’ instead.
⛔ Warning (comp): slime.el:3081:12: Warning: ‘beginning-of-sexp’ is an obsolete function (as of 25.1); use ‘thing-at-point--beginning-of-sexp’ instead.
⛔ Warning (comp): slime.el:3392:16: Warning: ‘beginning-of-sexp’ is an obsolete function (as of 25.1); use ‘thing-at-point--beginning-of-sexp’ instead.
⛔ Warning (comp): slime.el:3681:20: Warning: ‘find-tag-marker-ring’ is an obsolete variable (as of 25.1); use ‘xref-push-marker-stack’ or ‘xref-go-back’ instead.
⛔ Warning (comp): slime.el:4113:2: Warning: docstring has wrong usage of unescaped single quotes (use \= or different quoting)
⛔ Warning (comp): slime.el:4960:6: Warning: ‘font-lock-fontify-buffer’ is for interactive use only; use ‘font-lock-ensure’ or ‘font-lock-flush’ instead.
⛔ Warning (comp): slime.el:5536:10: Warning: ‘inhibit-point-motion-hooks’ is an obsolete variable (as of 25.1); use ‘cursor-intangible-mode’ or ‘cursor-sensor-mode’ instead
⛔ Warning (comp): slime.el:5692:10: Warning: ‘inhibit-point-motion-hooks’ is an obsolete variable (as of 25.1); use ‘cursor-intangible-mode’ or ‘cursor-sensor-mode’ instead
⛔ Warning (comp): slime.el:5795:10: Warning: ‘inhibit-point-motion-hooks’ is an obsolete variable (as of 25.1); use ‘cursor-intangible-mode’ or ‘cursor-sensor-mode’ instead
⛔ Warning (comp): slime.el:6329:8: Warning: Obsolete calling convention for 'sit-for'
⛔ Warning (comp): slime.el:6611:2: Warning: docstring has wrong usage of unescaped single quotes (use \= or different quoting)
⛔ Warning (comp): slime.el:7187:4: Warning: ‘easy-menu-add’ is an obsolete function (as of 28.1); this was always a no-op in Emacs and can be safely removed.
⛔ Warning (comp): slime.el:7194:4: Warning: ‘easy-menu-add’ is an obsolete function (as of 28.1); this was always a no-op in Emacs and can be safely removed.
⛔ Warning (comp): slime.el:7312:2: Warning: docstring has wrong usage of unescaped single quotes (use \= or different quoting)
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-parse.el:319:20: Warning: Stray ‘declare’ form: (declare (ignore args))
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-repl.el:130:2: Warning: defvar `slime-repl-history-use-mark' docstring has wrong usage of unescaped single quotes (use \= or different quoting)
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-repl.el:138:2: Warning: docstring has wrong usage of unescaped single quotes (use \= or different quoting)
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-repl.el:978:2: Warning: docstring has wrong usage of unescaped single quotes (use \= or different quoting)
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-repl.el:1580:22: Warning: Stray ‘declare’ form: (declare (ignore args))
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-repl.el:1689:4: Warning: ‘easy-menu-add’ is an obsolete function (as of 28.1); this was always a no-op in Emacs and can be safely removed.
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-presentations.el:601:2: Warning: docstring wider than 80 characters
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-presentations.el:759:4: Warning: ‘easy-menu-add’ is an obsolete function (as of 28.1); this was always a no-op in Emacs and can be safely removed.
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-presentations.el:760:4: Warning: ‘easy-menu-add’ is an obsolete function (as of 28.1); this was always a no-op in Emacs and can be safely removed.
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-presentations.el:761:4: Warning: ‘easy-menu-add’ is an obsolete function (as of 28.1); this was always a no-op in Emacs and can be safely removed.
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-presentations.el:762:4: Warning: ‘easy-menu-add’ is an obsolete function (as of 28.1); this was always a no-op in Emacs and can be safely removed.
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-references.el:102:67: Warning: reference to free variable ‘name’
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-references.el:107:15: Warning: ‘:info’ called as a function
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-references.el:109:15: Warning: ‘t’ called as a function
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-references.el:109:15: Warning: the function ‘t’ is not known to be defined.
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-references.el:107:15: Warning: the function ‘:info’ is not known to be defined.
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-references.el:106:13: Warning: the function ‘case’ is not known to be defined.
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-package-fu.el:226:21: Warning: ‘looking-back’ called with 1 argument, but requires 2 or 3
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-package-fu.el:263:14: Warning: ‘looking-back’ called with 1 argument, but requires 2 or 3
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-trace-dialog.el:162:12: Warning: ‘inhibit-point-motion-hooks’ is an obsolete variable (as of 25.1); use ‘cursor-intangible-mode’ or ‘cursor-sensor-mode’ instead
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-trace-dialog.el:248:16: Warning: ‘inhibit-point-motion-hooks’ is an obsolete variable (as of 25.1); use ‘cursor-intangible-mode’ or ‘cursor-sensor-mode’ instead
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-trace-dialog.el:261:28: Warning: ‘inhibit-point-motion-hooks’ is an obsolete variable (as of 25.1); use ‘cursor-intangible-mode’ or ‘cursor-sensor-mode’ instead
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-trace-dialog.el:352:13: Warning: ‘inhibit-point-motion-hooks’ is an obsolete variable (as of 25.1); use ‘cursor-intangible-mode’ or ‘cursor-sensor-mode’ instead
⛔ Warning (comp): slime-trace-dialog.el:478:12: Warning: ‘inhibit-point-motion-hooks’ is an obsolete variable (as of 25.1); use ‘cursor-intangible-mode’ or ‘cursor-sensor-mode’ instead
```

I checked the output in `*Messages*`, but it's too voluminous to post here.  Here is the end of the output:

```
...
...
Warning: Optimization failure for make-ert-test: Handler: make-ert-test--cmacro
(error "Keyword argument :file-name not one of (:name :documentation :body :most-recent-result :expected-result-type :tags)")
Warning: Optimization failure for make-ert-test: Handler: make-ert-test--cmacro
(error "Keyword argument :file-name not one of (:name :documentation :body :most-recent-result :expected-result-type :tags)")
Warning: Optimization failure for make-ert-test: Handler: make-ert-test--cmacro
(error "Keyword argument :file-name not one of (:name :documentation :body :most-recent-result :expected-result-type :tags)")
Wrote /Users/7stud/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-2.29.1/contrib/test/slime-repl-tests.elc
Checking /Users/7stud/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-2.29.1/contrib/test...
Done (Total of 57 files compiled, 2 skipped in 4 directories)
ad-handle-definition: ‘slime-note.message’ got redefined
Package ‘slime’ installed.
Operation [ Install 1 ] finished
```

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/64819/why-is-slime-working-in-emacs-but-not-in-the-minimal-set-up

Comment: @tripleee, The question at your link states: **Inside emacs: `M-x slime`, I have slime working perfectly.**  Is that what you understood to be my state of affairs after reading my question?

Comment: The question seems to include more than what's relevant - e.g., Paredit.

Comment: @Drew, I wanted to show that I was able to successfully install and use one package with my emacs install.

Comment: The symptoms are consistent with Slime not being installed. The errors from the installation would probably be important to include.

Comment: @triplee, I uninstalled slime and reinstalled so I could see the warnings again.  The warnings are at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Are you getting this? https://github.com/slime/slime/issues/732

Comment: @triplee, No. I checked the output in `*Messages*`, and the warnings are voluminous, but at the end  the output says slime was installed. See the bottom of my question.

Comment: Once you have installed slime, restart emacs.  In that emacs evaluate `inferior-lisp-program`.  Is it `"sbcl`"?  If not, then emacs is not reading your `.emacs` file: that's the problem.

Comment: What if you add `(require 'slime)` in your emacs init file? (and/or type `M-x eval-expression RET` and eval it) Can you send run `M-x slime` ?

Comment: @Ehvince, What's an emacs init file?  Is that my .emacs file?

Comment: yes I mean your ".emacs" file (or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`).

Comment: @ignisvolens, Before installing slime, I typed `C-h v`, then I entered inferior-lisp-program, and a buffer opened that said, *inferior-lisp-program is a variable defined in ‘inf-lisp.el’. Its value is "lisp"*.  After installing slime, I did the same, and the buffer said: *inferior-lisp-program is a variable defined in ‘inf-lisp.el’.  Its value is "sbcl". Original value was "lisp"*.  I still get `M-x slime [No match]`.

Comment: @Ehvince,  I also removed `(require 'slime)` from my .emacs file, then quit emacs, relaunched emacs, and once again I got `M-x slime [No match]`, then I did `M-x eval-expression<Ret>`, and at the prompt I typed `(require 'slime)`, and then I did `M-x slime`, and that opened another window with the slime REPL, so that worked as well.  If you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there:

> However, when I type M-x slime, I get [No match]

you are missing

```
(require 'slime)
```

You must add this in your `~/.emacs` (or "~/.emacs.d/init.el") and you can evaluate in your current session with `M-:` or `M-x eval-expression<Ret> (require 'slime)<Ret>`.

Comment: The problem with putting `(require 'slime)` in your .emacs file is that if you have hundreds (thousands?) of other requires, all the packages will load on startup, which could take awhile. The current versions of emacs automatically load some type of stub for each of your packages, and it's not until you use the package that the package is actually loaded. That is all supposed to be done automatically for you when you install a package. Unfortunately, the NonGNU Elpa Package Archive made some kind of mistake with the slime package, and it won't autoload. They are working on a fix.

Comment: It seems like a misunderstanding around autoload files for packages.  I gather the slime developers have been maintaining an autoloads file by hand in the package repository, and hadn't marked the original source code with the relevant autoload cookies for *generating* such a file.  The intention is for Emacs to generate the autoloads file at package installation time based on the cookies it finds in the lisp sources -- and so when *that* happened, the generated file didn't match the original hand-rolled file.

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to get slime to work when I followed the slime install instructions.  I decided to look around for another emacs distribution and try something else.  I visited the [emacs4cl](https://github.com/susam/emacs4cl) repo, and they have a `.emacs` file you can download.  I decided to try that `.emacs` file with my current emacs install.

First, I moved the current `~/.emacs` file and the `~/.emacs.d/` directory to `~/.xemacs` and `~/.xemacs.d/`, then I put the .emacs file from emacs4cl in my home directory: ~/.emacs.  After that, I started up emacs, and once again there were lots of warnings from the various packages that were installed, but when I typed `M-x slime`, another window opened up:

[image]

Here's the [.emacs](https://github.com/susam/emacs4cl/blob/main/.emacs) file from emacs4cl:

```
;; Customize user interface.
(when (display-graphic-p)
  (tool-bar-mode 0)
  (scroll-bar-mode 0))
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)

;; Dark theme.
(load-theme 'wombat)
(set-face-background 'default "#111")

;; Use spaces, not tabs, for indentation.
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)

;; Highlight matching pairs of parentheses.
(setq show-paren-delay 0)
(show-paren-mode)

;; Workaround for https://debbugs.gnu.org/34341 in GNU Emacs <= 26.3.
(when (and (version< emacs-version "26.3") (>= libgnutls-version 30603))
  (setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3"))

;; Write customizations to a separate file instead of this file.
(setq custom-file (expand-file-name "custom.el" user-emacs-directory))
(load custom-file t)

;; Enable installation of packages from MELPA.
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
(unless package-archive-contents
  (package-refresh-contents))

;; Install packages.
(dolist (package '(slime paredit rainbow-delimiters))
  (unless (package-installed-p package)
    (package-install package)))

;; Configure SBCL as the Lisp program for SLIME.
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/usr/local/bin")
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")

;; Enable Paredit.
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'enable-paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'eval-expression-minibuffer-setup-hook 'enable-paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'ielm-mode-hook 'enable-paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'lisp-interaction-mode-hook 'enable-paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook 'enable-paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'slime-repl-mode-hook 'enable-paredit-mode)
(require 'paredit)
(defun override-slime-del-key ()
  (define-key slime-repl-mode-map
    (read-kbd-macro paredit-backward-delete-key) nil))
(add-hook 'slime-repl-mode-hook 'override-slime-del-key)

;; Enable Rainbow Delimiters.
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'rainbow-delimiters-mode)
(add-hook 'ielm-mode-hook 'rainbow-delimiters-mode)
(add-hook 'lisp-interaction-mode-hook 'rainbow-delimiters-mode)
(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook 'rainbow-delimiters-mode)
(add-hook 'slime-repl-mode-hook 'rainbow-delimiters-mode)

;; Customize Rainbow Delimiters.
(require 'rainbow-delimiters)
(set-face-foreground 'rainbow-delimiters-depth-1-face "#c66")  ; red
(set-face-foreground 'rainbow-delimiters-depth-2-face "#6c6")  ; green
(set-face-foreground 'rainbow-delimiters-depth-3-face "#69f")  ; blue
(set-face-foreground 'rainbow-delimiters-depth-4-face "#cc6")  ; yellow
(set-face-foreground 'rainbow-delimiters-depth-5-face "#6cc")  ; cyan
(set-face-foreground 'rainbow-delimiters-depth-6-face "#c6c")  ; magenta
(set-face-foreground 'rainbow-delimiters-depth-7-face "#ccc")  ; light gray
(set-face-foreground 'rainbow-delimiters-depth-8-face "#999")  ; medium gray
(set-face-foreground 'rainbow-delimiters-depth-9-face "#666")  ; dark gray
```

I opened a hello world `.lisp` file in the top window, `C-x C-f`.  Then I put the cursor to the right of the last parenthesis of a function definition, then I hit `C-x C-e`, and the name of the function appeared in the echo line below the slime window. But I couldn't execute the function in the slime repl: I got an error saying the function name wasn't recognized. I also noticed the rainbow parentheses weren't working.  Hold on...I just quit emacs and relaunched it, and now `C-x C-e` works as expected: I see the function name returned on the echo line below the slime window, then I can execute the function in the slime repl...and now I can see the rainbow parentheses.

Also, on my first try with the new .emacs file, when I put the cursor in the middle of a function and typed `C-c C-c`, the echo window said something like "unrecognized command", and now that works just like `C-x C-e`.  Hallelujah!

Here are the differences in the directories:

```
~/.emacs.d% ls
auto-save-list custom.el      eln-cache      elpa
~/.emacs.d% cd elpa
~/.emacs.d/elpa  ls
archives                         paredit-20221127.1452
gnupg                            rainbow-delimiters-20210515.1254
macrostep-20230813.2123          slime-20240125.1336

~/.xemacs.d% ls
auto-save-list eln-cache      elpa
~/.xemacs.d% cd elpa
~/.xemacs.d/elpa%  ls
archives               macrostep-0.9.2.signed slime-2.29.1
gnupg                  paredit-26             slime-2.29.1.signed
macrostep-0.9.2        paredit-26.signed
```

The directories look different, but I don't know what the significance of that is.

Some other things I did:

1. To increase font size: `C-x C-+`  (`command +` stopped working).
   Or, permanently set the font size in `~/.emacs`:

   ```
   (set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Menlo" :height 180)
   ;; The "height" is 100 times the font size.
   ```
2. To change meta key from command to option:  In .emacs I added:

   ```
    (setq mac-command-key-is-meta nil) ; set cmd-key to nil   
    (setq mac-option-modifier 'meta) ; set option-key to meta
   ```

Comment: I can see from the versions that you originally installed slime 2.29.1 from the Non-GNU ELPA archive, and in the new config you've installed a version from the MELPA archive.  I just tested `package-install`-ing 2.29.1 from Non-GNU ELPA on Emacs 29.2 and `M-x slime` was recognised.  If you were to remove your config entirely, then start Emacs and `package-install` slime, I imagine it would also work.  (In which case your problem would be something else in your original config.)

Comment: >  I couldn't execute the function in the slime repl
I believe this is because of C-x C-e, maybe in combination with the function not yet saved to disk. I'd advise to use C-c C-c to *compile* and load, not eval. Differences: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/emacs-ide.html#evaluating-and-compiling-lisp-in-slime

Comment: "> on my first try with the new .emacs file […] C-c C-c unrecognized"
Emacs Lisp doesn't support compiling an expression with C-c C-c, that's for CL.

Comment: @Ehvince, I think you misunderstood.  I was editing a .lisp file with a slime window open below it.

Comment: @phil, *If you were to remove your config entirely,*  -- I think I did that before installing emacs 29.1, yet slime wouldn't work.  What does "remove your entire config" entail?

Comment: Removing (or just renaming as a back-up) the init file and directory discussed at `C-h i g (emacs)Find Init` (the specific filenames may vary, as more than one possibility is supported for each).  `C-h v user-init-file` and `C-h v user-emacs-directory` will tell you what was chosen by the running instance (but note that if more than one of the possibilities actually exists on the filesystem, then deleting the one being used *now* would cause the other to be used *next time*; so you might still want to check the alternatives).

Comment: @Ehvince,  Putting `(require 'slime)` in my .emacs worked!  I also removed `(require 'slime)` from my .emacs file, then quit emacs, relaunched emacs, and once again I got `M-x slime [No match]`, then I did `M-x eval-expression<Ret>`, and at the prompt I typed `(require 'slime)`, and then I did `M-x slime`, and that opened another window with the slime REPL, so that worked as well.  If you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark the question as solved.

Comment: I find that confusing if you're using Emacs 29.2 -- since Emacs 27.1 packages are initialized before your init file is read, and initializing the slime package provides an autoload for `M-x slime`; so if you've used `package-install` to install `slime` then there wouldn't be a need to `require` it explicitly.  You haven't *inhibited* package initialization in an early-init.el file, have you?

Comment: @phils,  I opened an issue at the [slime repo](https://github.com/slime/slime/issues/808), and someone there said the NonGNU Elpa package archive removed the `slime-autoloads.el` file from the slime package.  My original question was about an emacs that downloaded the slime package from the NonGNU Elpa package archive.  On the other hand, the .emacs file in the answer I posted ended up downloading the slime package from the MELPA package archive.

Comment: I can't replicate that -- per my first comment in this thread: "I just tested `package-install`-ing 2.29.1 from Non-GNU ELPA on Emacs 29.2 and `M-x slime` was recognised." And if `slime-autoloads.el` was missing for this package, autoloads files would be missing for *all* packages (as the autoloads file is generated from the `;;;###autoload` cookies in the source code at the time the archive builds each package), so that seems unlikely to have escaped notice.

Comment: Heh... ok, it looks like they were missing a heap of autoload cookies and have fixed that in https://github.com/slime/slime/pull/809/files so I suspect you'll find that within the next 24 hours there will be a Non-GNU ELPA build that works for you (https://elpa.nongnu.org/nongnu/slime.html).  (I can't explain why the autoloads file I was getting seemed fine in that regard, but this bug/fix does align with what you're seeing.)

Comment: Hmm, looks like they're still mulling over some changes, so the next Non-GNU ELPA release might be further away.  (Packages are built daily, so once they've bumped their version number to indicate a new release, the new package should be available within 24 hours of that.)